# OpenGL shader debugging. NVIDIA Parallel nSight?

Tags: debugging, opengl, shader

Can someone give me a run-down on the utility or otherwise of using NVIDIA's parallel nsight (in Visual Studio) for debugging OpenGL 3.3/4.2 + shaders?  Is this possible?  Is it desirable?

If it is possible, what configuration makes it possible?  Do I need two cards in one machine, two machines?

Do ATI have a similar feature?

I've found debugging my OpenGL shaders to be hell, and I've tried other OpenGL debuggers, that seem not to work correctly or at all.

Comment: The Nsight Visual Studio Edition 3.0 RC1 (available early 2013) will support OpenGL shader debugging. The current 2.2 version only supports D3D10/11 HLSL shader debugging.

Comment: Ah, OK.  Thanks Greg.  Can you just add that as an answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: I'll upvote it personally, because it's great news! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nsight Visual Studio Edition 3.0 (available early 2013) will support OpenGL shader debugging. OpenGL support was [announced](http://nvidia.fullviewmedia.com/siggraph2012/ondemand/SS102.html) at SIGGRAPH 2012. The initial version will support OpenGL 4.2 core. Follow on versions will add additional extensions.

Answer (score 1):

If NSight is really coming out for OpenGL soon, it maybe not important, but...

I use gDEBugger. It was, and still is a great tool for OpenGL debugging; requires one card only, works on ATI and NVidia cards, and it's free.

However, since AMD bought it, they've managed to make it totally useless, so GRemedy version is, sadly, last usable one.

Comment: Yea, I tried gDEBugger and it was...well... what can I say?  It needs work :).